# How properly to read data from binary file to char array

Tags: c++

How can i properly write data from binary file to new char array.
I know that this question was asked several times here, but still i couldn't figure out how to do it properly.

This what i have so far..

```
struct Computer_Details {

      char computer_type[99];
      int release_year;
      float price;

    };


    Computer_Details pc_details;

      cout << "Enter Computer Type: ";
      cin.getline(pc_details.computer_type, 255);
      cout << "Enter Computer Release Date: ";
      cin >> pc_details.release_year;
      cout << "Enter Computer Price: ";
      cin >> pc_details.price;
      cout << "\n\n";

      //Create File
      ofstream file;
      file.open("PC_Database.data", ios::binary | ios::app);

      if (!file) cout << "Couldn't open file\n";
      else {
        file.write((char*)&pc_details, sizeof(Computer_Details));
        file.close();
      }


      ifstream readFile;
      readFile.open("PC_Database.data", ios::binary);
      if (!readFile) cout << "Couldn't Open File\n";
      else {
        readFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        int fileSize = readFile.tellg();
        int pcCount = fileSize / sizeof(Computer_Details);

        readFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        Computer_Details *pc_details = new Computer_Details[pcCount];
        readFile.read((char*)pc_details, pcCount * sizeof(Computer_Details));

        char *buff = new char[299];

        for (int i = 0; i < pcCount; i++)
        {
          //write to buff char
        }
        readFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: You can use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading binary file into char array in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935567/reading-binary-file-into-char-array-in-c)

Comment: this answer didn't help

Comment: off topic: length mismatch between `cin.getline(pc_details.computer_type, 255);` and `char computer_type[99]` that allows for overrunning `computer_type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably problem is size of your structure,
check sizes for structure and compare it to size of this structure:

```
struct Computer_Details {
      char computer_type[100];
      int release_year;
      float price;
    };
```

Same problem is when you trying to read/write structure which contains bool variable between two other types like int.

Try this :

```
readFile.read((char*)pc_details->computer_type, sizeof(Computer_Details::computer_type));
readFile.read((char*)pc_details->release_year, sizeof(Computer_Details::release_year));
readFile.read((char*)pc_details->price, sizeof(Computer_Details::price));
```

edit: look at examples in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/119128/7981164

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
std::ifstream input(szFileName, std::ios::binary);
data = std::vector<char>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
char* charArray = &data[0];
size_t arraySize = data.size();
```

`data` vector's buffer is the needed char array. Its constructor's arguments are two iterators. The first one is the current reading position in `ifstream` (begin of stream in this case). The second one's constructor is default and it is treated as an end iterator.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to shove pc_details into the buff so you can send it somewhere and reconstruct the data.

If that is the case, you could do this:

```
for( int i=0; i < pcCount; i++ )
{
    memcpy( buff, (char*)pc_details, sizeof(computer_details));
    buff += sizeof(computer_details);
    pc_details++;
}
```

However, when doing this you must be mindful of alignment and provide
padding accordingly.  And your code should check your array bounds.